How to receive field with brackets ex. contact[id] from webhook in c#
I am trying to receive a field with brackets [ ] ex. contact[id] from a webhook sent by a third party application (Active Campaign) to our API that is written in c#. As shown in the image below, brackets are not permitted in the parameter name.
I've tried adding an @ symbol before as I've seen suggested in other places. Any suggestions on how to accept fields with brackets or special characters is appreciated!



Try CreateContact([FromUri(Name = "account[id]")] string accountId)
